# Magento 2.3.2 Undefined offset Encryptor.php

Tags: magento2, user, admin-user

Magento 2.3.2 community edition
Nginx 1.16
PHP 7.2.19

Steps to reproduce (*)
1.login magento store admin

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /www/web/demo/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on
>   line 588"#1 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->getArgonHash()
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:278]\n#2
>   Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->isValidHash() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php:266]\n#3
>   Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->validateHash() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:608]\n#4
>   Magento\User\Model\User->verifyIdentity() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:206]\n#5
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->verifyIdentity() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:580]\n#6
>   Magento\User\Model\User->authenticate() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#7
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->___callParent() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#8
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/mirasvit/module-event/src/Event/Event/Admin/LoginEvent.php:135]\n#9
>   Mirasvit\Event\Event\Admin\LoginEvent->aroundAuthenticate() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#10
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#11
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:195]\n#12
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->authenticate() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php:635]\n#13
>   Magento\User\Model\User->login() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:219]\n#14
>   Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->login() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php:162]\n#15
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#16
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#17
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#18
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php:78]\n#19
>   Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login() called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:205]\n#20
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:157]\n#21
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:125]\n#22
>   Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]\n#23
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#24
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:39]\n#25
>   Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]\n#26
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]\n#27
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#28
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#29
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]\n#32
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]\n#33
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#34
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at
>   [pub/index.php:40]\n","url":"/m_demo/admin/index/index/key/ed11bf3331221182a6/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Do you have Libsodium module installed and enabled on your server?

Answer (score 17):

For me executing this query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Fixed my problem. I found the answer here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23511

Comment: this works for me, **try this first** and move on to other solutions.

Comment: Please remember to replace the xxxxxxxx with the crypt key located in your env.php

    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'xxxxxxxx'
    ],

Answer (score 10):

Even I got the same notice message when I try to login into **Magento2 admin panel**, after **upgrading Magento2** from **2.3.1** to **2.3.2**

For me, it got solved after installing **PHP version 7.2** and installing the php7.2-sodium extension.

Comment: It is working fine

Answer (score 6):

I just got exactly the same warning msg and couldn't log in to my Magento 2 admin backend.

I don't know why this is happening and couldn't find any more info online about this.

My workaround this problem was to run this command

> magento admin:user:create

add a new admin user and then connect fine.

I couldn't wait for this to be solved to do my work.

Answer (score 3):

I got the issue when I login to backend after clone site magento 2.

I'm using PHP version 7.2 and i tried to install the php7.2-sodium extension.

```
apt-get install php-sodium
```

It work for me.

P/S: I'm using nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

"libsodium" is required for the new magento version. For me i fixed it with installing libsodium and afterwards installing the php extension with pecl:

```
curl https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz -o /tmp/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz 
tar -xzf /tmp/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz -C /tmp 
cd /tmp/libsodium-1.0.18
./configure && make && make check && make install

pecl install libsodium
echo extension=sodium.so > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sodium.ini (your extension directory may be different)
```

There is already an ticket on github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23405

For me installing libsodium-dev and php-sodium (inside a docker container) was not working so compiled it from source and used pecl for the php extension..

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my admin user and recreate it to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this. For me the solution was to **delete all admin account before creating new ones**. Somehow a bad account gets in the way of all new accounts? I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Delete your admin user from the database and create a new one with `php bin/magento admin:user:create`